# System.NullException when using NavigationService.Navigate to navigate to the Mainpage and pass a value to the main page

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, template10

I have an app with two HamburgerMenuButtons: TYMLY and NEWTYMLY. TYMLY is the mainpage. I am using the Template10 MVVM. On the startup It navigates to the TYMLY page as required, I tap on the NEWTYMLY page and proceed to carryout some tasks to create a Object that is meant to be added to the Griview in the TYMLY mainpage. In the PageHeader section I have a button that is meant to save this object and proceed to Navigate to the TYMLY mainpage and add the object to the Gridview.
Anytime I press this button I get the System.NullException on the following line:

```
public void SaveNewTymly() =>
        NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(Views.MainPage), New_Tymly);
```

I also noticed the System.NullException als ooccures if I press other buttons that come with the template like Settings, Privacy and About Us;

```
public void GotoSettings() =>
        NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(Views.SettingsPage), 0);

    public void GotoPrivacy() =>
        NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(SettingsPage), 1);

    public void GotoAbout() =>
        NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(Views.SettingsPage), 2);
```

I want to know how I am to handle Navigation in this case.
Thank you.
[MainPage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGDf5.png)
[NewPage to create object to add to the gridview in the mainpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Td2hw.png)

NewTymlyModel.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Template10.Mvvm;
using Template10.Services.NavigationService;
using Tymly_Revamped.Models;
using Tymly_Revamped.Views;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace Tymly_Revamped.ViewModels
{
    class NewTymlyViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private Tymly newTymly;
        public Tymly New_Tymly { get { return newTymly; } set { Set(ref newTymly, value); } }


    bool trafficFlow;





    public NewTymlyViewModel()
    {
      newTymly = new Tymly();
    }

    public override async Task OnNavigatedToAsync(object parameter, NavigationMode mode, IDictionary<string, object> suspensionState)
    {
        New_Tymly = (suspensionState.ContainsKey(nameof(New_Tymly))) ? suspensionState[nameof(New_Tymly)] as Tymly : parameter as Tymly;
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public override async Task OnNavigatedFromAsync(IDictionary<string, object> suspensionState, bool suspending)
    {
        if (suspending)
        {


            suspensionState[nameof(New_Tymly)] = New_Tymly;
        }
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

  public bool TrafficFlow
    {
        get { return trafficFlow; Debug.WriteLine(trafficFlow); }
        set { trafficFlow = !trafficFlow; }

    }

    public override async Task OnNavigatingFromAsync(NavigatingEventArgs args)
    {
        args.Cancel = false;
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void SaveNewTymly() =>
        NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(Views.MainPage), New_Tymly);


    public void GotoSettings() =>
        NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(Views.SettingsPage), 0);

    public void GotoPrivacy() =>
        NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(SettingsPage), 1);

    public void GotoAbout() =>
        NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(Views.SettingsPage), 2);
}
```

}

```
using NodaTime.TimeZones;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Devices.Geolocation;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps;
using Tymly_Revamped.Models;
using Tymly_Revamped.ViewModels;
using Tymly_Revamped.Views;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
namespace Tymly_Revamped.Views
{

    public sealed partial class NewTymly : Page
    {


    private uint desiredAccuracy_meters = 0;
    private CancellationTokenSource cancelTokenSrc = null;

    private IEnumerable<string> zonalIds;

    IReadOnlyList<GetContactDetails> condetails;
    public IReadOnlyList<GetContactDetails> ConDetails { get { return condetails; } set { condetails = value; } }
    ObservableCollection<GetContactDetails> contacts;
    public ObservableCollection<GetContactDetails> Contacts { get { return contacts; } set { contacts = value; } }

    public NewTymly()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        NavigationCacheMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
        DataContext = new NewTymlyViewModel();
        searchLocation.Loaded += Map_Loaded;
        searchLocation.MapTapped += Map_Tapped;
        searchLocation.MapDoubleTapped += Map_DoubledTapped;
        searchLocation.Style = MapStyle.Road;
    }

    private void Map_DoubledTapped(MapControl sender, MapInputEventArgs args)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void Map_Tapped(MapControl sender, MapInputEventArgs args)
    {
        var tappedPositon = args.Location.Position;
         if (sender.ZoomLevel < 20)
        {
            sender.ZoomLevel += 2;
        }
        else if (sender.ZoomLevel >= 20)
        {
            sender.ZoomLevel = 12;
        }
    }

    private async void Map_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        try
        {
            var requestLocationAccess = await Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync();
            switch (requestLocationAccess)
            {
                case GeolocationAccessStatus.Allowed:
                    cancelTokenSrc = new CancellationTokenSource();
                    CancellationToken token = cancelTokenSrc.Token;


                    Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator { DesiredAccuracyInMeters = desiredAccuracy_meters };
                    Geoposition pos = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync().AsTask(token);

                    searchLocation.Center =
                        new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition()
                        {
                            Latitude = pos.Coordinate.Point.Position.Latitude,
                            Longitude = pos.Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude
                        });
                    searchLocation.ZoomLevel = 1;                        
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException)
        {
            throw new TaskCanceledException();
        }
        finally
        {
            cancelTokenSrc = null;
        }
    }

    private async void ShowOnMap(double lati, double longi)
    {
        try
        {
            var accessLocation = await Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync();

            switch (accessLocation)
            {

                case GeolocationAccessStatus.Allowed:
                    cancelTokenSrc = new CancellationTokenSource();
                    CancellationToken token = cancelTokenSrc.Token;


                    Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator { DesiredAccuracyInMeters = desiredAccuracy_meters };
                    Geoposition pos = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync().AsTask(token);

                    searchLocation.Center =
                        new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition()
                        {
                            Latitude = lati,
                            Longitude = longi,
                        });
                    searchLocation.ZoomLevel = 5;
                    break;

            }
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            cancelTokenSrc = null;
        }
    }

    private void styleCombobox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (mapStyle.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                searchLocation.Style = MapStyle.None;
                break;
            case 1:
                searchLocation.Style = MapStyle.Road;
                break;
            case 2:
                searchLocation.Style = MapStyle.Aerial;
                break;
            case 3:
                searchLocation.Style = MapStyle.AerialWithRoads;
                break;
            case 4:
                searchLocation.Style = MapStyle.Terrain;
                break;
        }
    }

    public void InputLocation_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Reason == AutoSuggestionBoxTextChangeReason.UserInput)
        {
            zonalIds = TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default.ZoneLocations.
                Where(loc => loc.CountryName.IndexOf(sender.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > -1).
                Select(loc => loc.ZoneId);
            sender.ItemsSource = zonalIds.ToList();
        }
    }

    public void InputLocation_QuerySubmitted(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxQuerySubmittedEventArgs args)
    {
        MapGlyphs mapGlyph = new MapGlyphs();
        if (args.ChosenSuggestion != null)
        {
            var selectedZonalId = args.ChosenSuggestion as string;

            string state = selectedZonalId.Remove(0, selectedZonalId.IndexOf("/") + 1).Replace("_", " ");

            var country = TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default.ZoneLocations.
            Where(zoneloc => zoneloc.ZoneId == selectedZonalId).Select(zoneloc => zoneloc.CountryName).
            ElementAtOrDefault(0);

            var timeZone = TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default.ZoneLocations.
                Where(tym => tym.ZoneId == selectedZonalId).Select(tymZone => TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default.WindowsMapping.
                MapZones.FirstOrDefault(tym => tym.TzdbIds.Contains(selectedZonalId))).
                Where(tym => tym != null).Select(tym => tym.WindowsId).Distinct();

            var lattitude = TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default.ZoneLocations.
                Where(lat => lat.ZoneId == selectedZonalId).Select(tym => tym.Latitude);

            var longitude = TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default.ZoneLocations.
                Where(lon => lon.ZoneId == selectedZonalId).Select(tym => tym.Longitude);

            if (timeZone.Count() != 0)
            {
                var dateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(
                    DateTime.Now, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZone.ElementAt(0)));
                if (mapGlyph.PlaceIcon.ContainsKey(state))
                {
                    locationText.Text = state;
                    ViewModel.New_Tymly.Location = state;
                    ViewModel.New_Tymly.MapIcon = mapGlyph.MapLocationIcon(state);
                }
                else
                {
                    locationText.Text = country;
                    ViewModel.New_Tymly.Location = country;
                    ViewModel.New_Tymly.MapIcon = mapGlyph.MapLocationIcon(country);
                }

                dateText.Text = dateTime.ToString("D");
                timeText.Text = dateTime.ToString("T");
                ViewModel.New_Tymly.Datetime = dateTime;
                IconPath.Data = PathMarkupToGeometry(ViewModel.New_Tymly.MapIcon);
            }
            else
            {

            }
            ShowOnMap(lattitude.ElementAt(0), longitude.ElementAt(0));
        }
    }

    public void InputLocation_SuggestionChosen(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxSuggestionChosenEventArgs args)
    {
        MapGlyphs mapGlyph = new MapGlyphs();
        var place = args.SelectedItem as string;
        string state = place.Remove(0, place.IndexOf("/") + 1).Replace("_", " ");

        var country = TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default.ZoneLocations.
        Where(zoneloc => zoneloc.ZoneId == place).Select(zoneloc => zoneloc.CountryName).
        ElementAtOrDefault(0);
        var timeZone = TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default.ZoneLocations.
                Where(x => x.ZoneId == place).Select(tz => TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default.WindowsMapping.
                MapZones.FirstOrDefault(x => x.TzdbIds.Contains(place))).
                Where(x => x != null).Select(x => x.WindowsId).Distinct();
        var latitude = TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default.ZoneLocations.
            Where(x => x.ZoneId == place).Select(tz => tz.Latitude);
        var longitude = TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default.ZoneLocations.
            Where(x => x.ZoneId == place).Select(tz => tz.Longitude);

        if (timeZone.Count() != 0)
        {
            var dateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(
                DateTime.Now, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZone.ElementAt(0)));
            if (mapGlyph.PlaceIcon.ContainsKey(state))
            {
                locationText.Text = state;
                ViewModel.New_Tymly.Location = state;
                ViewModel.New_Tymly.MapIcon = mapGlyph.MapLocationIcon(state);
            }
            else
            {
                locationText.Text = country;
                ViewModel.New_Tymly.Location = country;
                ViewModel.New_Tymly.MapIcon = mapGlyph.MapLocationIcon(country);
            }

            dateText.Text = dateTime.ToString("D");
            timeText.Text = dateTime.ToString("T");
            ViewModel.New_Tymly.Datetime = dateTime;
            IconPath.Data = PathMarkupToGeometry(ViewModel.New_Tymly.MapIcon);
        }
        else
        {

        }

        ShowOnMap(latitude.ElementAt(0), longitude.ElementAt(0));
    }

    Geometry PathMarkupToGeometry(string pathMarkup)
    {
        string xaml =
        "<Path " +
        "xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'>" +
        "<Path.Data>" + pathMarkup + "</Path.Data></Path>";
        var path = XamlReader.Load(xaml) as Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Path;
        // Detach the PathGeometry from the Path
        Geometry geometry = path.Data;
        path.Data = null;
        return geometry;
    }

    private async void AddContacts(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        var contactPicker = new ContactPicker();
        contactPicker.DesiredFieldsWithContactFieldType.Add(ContactFieldType.Email);
        contactPicker.DesiredFieldsWithContactFieldType.Add(ContactFieldType.PhoneNumber);

        var selectedContacts = await contactPicker.PickContactsAsync();
        ContactStore contactStore = await ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync(ContactStoreAccessType.AllContactsReadOnly);


        if (selectedContacts != null && selectedContacts.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in selectedContacts)
            {
                Contact realContact = await contactStore.GetContactAsync(item.Id);

                ViewModel.New_Tymly.ContactList.Add(new ContactItemAdapter(realContact));
                var t = new ContactItemAdapter(realContact).Thumbnail;
                Debug.WriteLine(t);

            }
        }

    }

    private void DeleteContact(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ContactItemAdapter item = (ContactItemAdapter)(sender as Button).DataContext;
        Debug.WriteLine(item.Name);
        if (addContacts.Items.Contains(item))
        {
            ViewModel.New_Tymly.ContactList.Remove(item);
        }
    }


}
```

}

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, please post your sample.

Comment: The XAML Page for the respective code above is as follows    https://1drv.ms/u/s!At8wfXXlpL7gkpEEWZmPvMaWyTkdNA

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem using your posted code, but still I can't reproduce this navigation problem, here is my [demo](https://github.com/GraceFeng/Template10-Navigation-Doesn-t-Work-Case-Demo).

Comment: Your Demo will work correctly, here is a link to the project file https://1drv.ms/u/s!At8wfXXlpL7gkp1tJxTNEsFJ-PUTRg there are two pages of importance the MainPage and the NewTymlyPage

Comment: I tested your sample both in debug mode and release mode, first you selected the "Optimize code" in x86 debug mode, it is not necessary. Then, your app still works fine by my side. The only difference I found is that template 10 package's version in my demo is 1.1.10, and yours is 1.1.11, and my OS version is 10586, and mobile version is 10240.

Comment: Did you click n the newtymly page and procced to click on the settings or privacy or about us tab in the page header for the NewTymly page?